# a faster (than express) nodejs static files server / express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

Does there exist a middleware for serving images found on disk that is faster than express' static middleware?

I am dancing around rewriting a bunch of code to work with nginx. I am writing an IMGUR* clone - so ill be serving a lot of images. keeping is as a middleware would be nice since I would be keeping the option to do some pre-processing before serving the images.

Comment: 14k rep and using stack overflow instead of npmjs.org/github.org. Do you really need help with this or are you just covering your ass?

Comment: 21K rep and sounding like an ass in a comment ;) npmjs.org does not tell you what the good npms are. Take for example this: https://npmjs.org/search?q=imagemagick the first hit looks great, but its actually a huge buggy unmaintained POS. I asked a question about an imagemagick lib here and was told. I am looking for anecdotal knowledge.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but you're better off putting those assets behind nginx or a CDN after you process them and avoid serving static with node. You could benchmark middleware with my [express-debug](https://github.com/devoidfury/express-debug) tool; if you do let me know what you find.

Comment: heh - funny that you should comment here since i asked you on github a few weeks ago about express-debug. Yes, I am planning to use it soon for stuff

Comment: In a scenario like yours, I'd make sure to have that middleware near the top of your middleware stack to bail out of the chain as early as possible.

Comment: I think nothing can beat a cdn for static files. Have you given thought to amazon cloud front? Other wise I think `send` the middleware that express uses is pretty fast. You will save yourself a lot of time, money and energy if you just went with cloudfront.

Comment: well probably not money ;) express/nginx is free

Comment: @mkoryak ha ha I meant it will save a lot of money with server resources. I can't think of any hosting services that would cheaply allow gigs of storage and images will fill up those hard disks fast.

Comment: Most efficient way is to use `try_files` with disabled logging and forced caching from nginx side. As well post-processing images in advance would be much more efficient rather than on-request. So you can upload images to one folder (private), have node process that will post-process images, and then copy it over to public directory that `try_files` has access to. That would be most efficient way to serve images using node+nginx.